# Alternative to "Could you please"?

Tags: politeness

I have been using the following phrase when requesting information through email.

> Could you please ...?

For example, "could you please send me the required documents?".
As English is not my first language, I am not sure whether this sounds offensive to recipient.

What is an alternative to the phrase above?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that could be offensive!?  It is polite, even highly polite. It uses two polite expressions:  "please" and the tentative "could you".

As for alternatives. You could more tentative with "Would it be possible for you to send me..."

Business emails should normally be fairly simple and direct. Adding "please" is good. But complex or "flowery" language like "would it be possible" should be avoided. So the less polite but more direct expression "Please send me..." is better. This would be my way of phrasing a simple business request.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. Yes I have been trying to write business emails as succinct as possible. If possible, could you please introduce me to some related books? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Kindly send me the required documents" can be an alternative way to say that.

Comment: That seems over-polite to me which JamesK has already suggested is not appropriate for a business email.

Comment: I would assume the author is Indian.